# Automatically connect bluetooth mouse

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth mouse (Apple Mighty Mouse) which I use with Kubuntu (KDE). I always have to manually connect to the mouse, although it is listed as a trusted device. How can I automatically connect the mouse when I have it turned on? Or at least reconnect after suspend?

Comment: You might want to try the method mentioned here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup

Comment: That looks deprecated, I do not have a `/etc/default/bluetooth` config, but a `/etc/bluetooth` folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hciconfig` to do that.

First manually connect your mouse as you usually do, then open a terminal and run `hciconfig -a` to retrieve its name. It should be something like `hciX` where `X` is the number of your device. You can either use `hcitool scan`, it should give the name as well.

Once this is done, you can force the bluetooth device detection by running

```
sudo hciconfig <name_of_your_mouse> reset
```

In order to do that automatically at every boot, you want to edit `/etc/init.d/bluetooth` and append the magic line at the end of the file : `hciconfig <name_of_your_mouse> reset`. Then save, reboot, and it should work forever.

Also make sure that your mouse is plugged in at boot time. If you plug it in after booting you will have to manually detect the mouse again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Logitech bluetooth travel mouse. I have Ubuntu 20.04. My laptop is a Lenovo ideapad.
How to fix Bluetooth in Ubuntu

First, if bluez is installed. make sure the mouse is detected and paired. If not remove mouse icon, press the button on the mouse to pair and reconnect the mouse.

next:
open terminal

To turn it on enter:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

To make it permanent when booting up the system enter:

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
```

Also:

```
rfkill list # to see if anything is blocked
```

And to remove and reinstall the bluetooth stack and programs if it is corrupted use:

```
sudo apt purge python-bluez  
sudo apt install python-bluez
```

Install blueman:

```
sudo apt install blueman
```

Edit the main.conf file:

```
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

uncomment `ReconnectAttemps=7` (remove `#` character) and also uncomment (remove #)

```
AutoEnable=true
```

Save, exit nano and reboot.

To remove blueman icon in upper right corner, right-click on blueman icon then uncheck appindicator under plugins.

Make sure to close cover and turn off mouse. Wait for suspend mode to occur (blinking power light), then turn on mouse then open lid on.
The mouse will automatically connect.