# SOLVED - Microsoft Designer Mouse not connecting to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: bluetooth, 15.10

I've just bought a Microsoft designer mouse which uses bluetooth to connect rather than a dongle, but for some reason my laptop simply won't recognise the device.

Pairing the devices didn't work via GUI so I opened a terminal, ran `bluetoothctl` and then `scan on` but still can't see the MAC address of the mouse.

I've done some research into this and have seen suggestions to edit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf and have also tried this but still no joy. I've also tried to completely remove bluez and blueman and re-install, but it's still not working.

Have I made a boo boo in choosing this mouse?

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Designer Mouse needs to have Bluetooth 4 to work, I bought this mouse a month ago and had to return it, because I had version < 4.

You can find your bluetooth version with command `hciconfig -a | grep HCI`

See the (0xY) where Y is:

```
0 Bluetooth Core Specification 1.0b 
1 Bluetooth Core Specification 1.1 
2 Bluetooth Core Specification 1.2 
3 Bluetooth Core Specification 2.0 + EDR 
4 Bluetooth Core Specification 2.1 + EDR 
5 Bluetooth Core Specification 3.0 + HS 
6 Bluetooth Core Specification 4.0 ​ ​
7 ​Bluetooth Core Specification 4.1 ​ 
​8 ​​Bluetooth Core Specification 4.2 
9 - 255 Reserved
```

[Source of this specification ...](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/host-controller-interface)

So you need at least HCI Version: ... (0x6) ... to make it work.

Comment: Yup it looks like mine is 0x5...dang. I don't suppose there's a way to upgrade your HCI?

Comment: @Daemon4 You can buy a Bluetooth 4 adapter, for example as a USB dongle and use it to connect to you keyboard. If you find my answer helpful or answer to your question, please rate it or mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Mike Thank you for the answer. Can you please take a look at [this question1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/736674/connecting-a-bluetooth-4-0-le-mouse-microsoft-mobile-mouse-3600). I have the problem too and I might share it with many. Like in this related questions:
[q2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/736681/microsoft-designer-mouse-pairs-but-does-not-move), [q3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/646433/microsoft-designer-mouse-bluetooth-4-0-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts?rq=1), etc.