# Microsoft designer mouse, pairs but does not move?

Tags: mouse, 15.10, bluetooth

Just bought a bluetooth mouse called "Microsoft designer mouse". It pairs successfully according to Ubuntu 15.10, but there is no reaction when I move or click.
Any advice?

Output of `~ $  dpkg -l | grep blue`:

```
ii  bluez          5.35-0ubuntu amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-cups     5.35-0ubuntu amd64        Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-obexd    5.35-0ubuntu amd64        bluez obex daemon
ii  gnome-bluetoot 3.16.1-1ubun amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools
ii  indicator-blue 0.0.6+15.10. amd64        System bluetooth indicator.
ii  libbluetooth3: 5.35-0ubuntu amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bl
ii  libgnome-bluet 3.16.1-1ubun amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools - support l
```

Comment: similar but on an older O/S - so have a look through and see what is relevant to your question and add some details to your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/646433/microsoft-designer-mouse-bluetooth-4-0-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: please respond to queries by edit your question.  Its very difficult to understand stuff like above written in comment form.  Thanks.

Comment: [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/646433/microsoft-designer-mouse-bluetooth-4-0-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts?rq=1) (answer from Chris McCormick) worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a lot of work?
Dont have the time at the moment, hopefully it will be fixed in the future?