# Using Microsoft Designer Keyboard and Mouse with ubuntu 16.04 (on a dell xps 13)

Tags: keyboard, 16.04, mouse, dell, microsoft

I have the new developer edition of the Dell XPS 13, which comes with ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Since the new LTS is released already I decided to upgrade to 16.04, which should support BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) devices such as the Microsoft Designer Keyboard and Mouse. But I'm not able to get it working.

If I try to pair the mouse, it fails:

```
 ~ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 44:85:00:2C:E5:E7 laptop [default]
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 44:85:00:2C:E5:E7 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13 Designer Mouse
[bluetooth]# pair E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13
Attempting to pair with E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13
[CHG] Device E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13 UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13 UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13 UUIDs: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13 UUIDs: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13 UUIDs: 00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[Designer Mouse]# connect E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13
Attempting to connect to E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13
Connection successful
[CHG] Device E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13 Connected: no
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

Some more logs can be found in the syslog:

```
May 19 18:05:11 laptop kernel: [29453.178205] Bluetooth: SMP security requested but not available
May 19 18:05:11 laptop bluetoothd[1154]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0009 for device E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13
May 19 18:05:11 laptop bluetoothd[1154]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x000e for device E5:4B:7C:B0:25:13
May 19 18:05:12 laptop bluetoothd[1154]: Error reading PNP_ID value: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
May 19 18:05:13 laptop bluetoothd[1154]: Error reading Report value: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
May 19 18:05:13 laptop bluetoothd[1154]: message repeated 3 times: [ Error reading Report value: Attribute requires authentication before read/write]
May 19 18:05:14 laptop bluetoothd[1154]: Report Map read failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
May 19 18:05:14 laptop bluetoothd[1154]: Protocol Mode characteristic read failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
May 19 18:05:14 laptop bluetoothd[1154]: HID Information read failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
May 19 18:05:14 laptop bluetoothd[1154]: Read Report Reference descriptor failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write
May 19 18:05:14 laptop bluetoothd[1154]: message repeated 3 times: [ Read Report Reference descriptor failed: Attribute requires authentication before read/write]
```

I wonder if the line "SMP security ..." might be important? I found this link, where the author of the correct answer describes how he "patches" his own hid-file, but doing so did not help: [Microsoft Designer Mouse (Bluetooth 4.0) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646433/microsoft-designer-mouse-bluetooth-4-0-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

When trying to connect the keyboard the results and logs are pretty similar (only the addresses change), so I omitted them here.

Hope anyone has a helpful hint for me?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I also have problems with the same mouse (Microsoft Designer), same computer (dell XPS 13) and same Ubuntu version (16.04). But for me pairing is not an issue. The problem is that the every once in a while the mouse stops working. I temporarly solve this by switching off and on the bluetooth applet indicator, so the mouse start working again but then it will stop again and so on.
I tried installing blueman but the issue remains the same.
Do you have a similar problem or just the pairing issue?

Answer (score 0):

I updated to latest bluez version from 17.04. It's fixed there according to debian bug ticket.
I just downloaded the file manually.

Comment: I've done it as well, but after a few minutes without using the keyboard it goes idle and it does not work anymore. Any suggestions for this problem?