# Microsoft Designer Mouse + Keyboard disconnects on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, 16.10

I have the Dell XPS 13 and in contrast to [Using Microsoft Designer Keyboard and Mouse with ubuntu 16.04 (on a dell xps 13)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774771/using-microsoft-designer-keyboard-and-mouse-with-ubuntu-16-04-on-a-dell-xps-13), it works out-of-the-box! Great. It is a low power bluetooth mouse and keyboard combination.

The issue is that if I do not type for a minute or so (as frequently happens) it appears as if the keyboard or mouse seems as if it needs to reconnect. Am I missing some power saving settings somehere?

Comment: I am having the same problem and have not found a solution.